# Django-wkhtmltopdf crashes on server

Tags: django, django-wkhtmltopdf

I have an app using `django-wkhtmltopdf`.  It is working locally, but when I run on a VPS I'm getting the following error.

> Command '['wkhtmltopdf', '--allow', 'True',
>   '--enable-local-file-access', '--encoding', 'utf8',
>   '--javascript-delay', '2000', '--page-height', '465mm',
>   '--page-width', '297mm', '--quiet', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdffyknjyrk.html',
>   '-']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

I'm guessing I need to set some permissions on the VPS to allow the temp file to be created (or set a directory for it) but I'm not sure how to do this.

Within `settings.py` I have

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD_OPTIONS = {
    'quiet': True,
    'allow' : '/tmp',
    'javascript-delay' : 1000,
    'enable-local-file-access' : True,
}
```

And within the django view I've got:

```
cmd_options = {
    #'window-status' : 'ready',
    'javascript-delay': 2000,
    'page-height' : '465mm',
    'page-width' : '297mm',
    'allow' : True,
    #'T' : 0, 'R' : 0, 'B' : 0, 'L': 0,
    }
```

Comment: Did you add WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD in your settings files

Comment: No, but it is clearly finding and running wkhtmltopdf so do I need to?  It runs locally without it

Comment: You must configure that

Comment: Done - same error